# angular run build error - error TS1256: A rest element must be last in a tuple type

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, azure-pipelines, angularbuild

I have an angular application in which i am facing issue while building on azure pipeline

```
ERROR in node_modules/socket.io-client/build/esm/socket.d.ts:29:56 - error TS1256: A rest element must be last in a tuple type.

29 export declare type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer H, infer L] ? L : any;
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/socket.io-client/build/esm/socket.d.ts:30:62 - error TS1256: A rest element must be last in a tuple type.

30 export declare type AllButLast<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer H, infer L] ? H : any[];
```

node version : `14.18.1`

from the error it seems, it is due to

```
"socket.io-client": "^4.0.1",
```

library.

when i run the build on local it works fine, but I am facing above error on azure.

I deleted the `package-lock.json` on local and push the code, but still the same issue

what can be the possible issue?